# How do I run a function in a print statement? Where the function itself contains a print statement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a variable to be used in more than one place to print a line of script

I tried using this to print: `print(helped)`, didn't work, it gave the error you see. I tried doing this: print helped(), gave a syntax error

```
def helped():
     print('''Type
Type
Type''')

weirdness = input('''What function would you like to run?
Type "Help" for possible commands ''')

if weirdness.upper() == "HELP":
    print (helped)
```

When I enter "helped" upon being prompted, I get:
What function would you like to run?
Type "Help" for possible commands helped
I think you need a bit of help

instead of getting the print statement

How do i resolve the issue such that this wont happen?

Comment: You have to *call* the function. `print(helped())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python when calling a function, you must use the parentheses. So since your function's name is `helped`, you should call it like this:

```
print( helped() )
```

You should do this regardless of whether your function has parameters.

On a side note, with Python 2.6, you could have also use the print function without parentheses like this:

```
print helped()
```

but this is not the case with Python 3.x

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to execute the function. Currently, the `helped()` function is defined but not run in your code. Essentially, it's never used. Right now you use `print (helped)` and should be getting a error when instead, you should [call](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp) the function

Change

```
print(helped)
```

to

```
print(helped())
```